# Marlin g-codes applicable for a Melzi Sanguino board

Tags: arduino-uno

How/where do I find a complete listing of "acceptable" Marlin g-codes applicable to a Melzi Sanguino board on a 3D printer (Zonestar). It appears that not all printer boards accept all available Marlin codes.

---

Then I was thinking incorrectly. I had assumed that not all g-codes (from a Marlin build) were, in fact, “implemented” the same way on all boards, and some would not even be recognized or interpreted. But I still don’t understand why that is.

Comment: It depends what software is installed on the board. The board doesn't define the codes, the software does.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? G Code is a broad standard. The developers if a firmware might think, that some G codes are not needed for the purpose, that the firmware is meant for. Thus they might decide to not implement them. Implementing all possible G codes would be a time consuming task. As much of this is open source, the developers might want to save some resources for imortant stuff

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

As already written in the comments the software defines what G-Codes are taken by a (printer) board
**BUT** Even if the software has the same name (eg Marlin) it might behave different on different boards because of:

- different release versions for different hardware
- different release repositories being ahead or behind the master repo
- hardware specific features a G-code triggers (most unlikely)

The clever way is to go from features I need to software supporting thosefeatures to boards supported AND useable for my hardware to controll (3d-printer/CNC-router/laser-cutter aso) 
  -